# To how many decimal places is bc accurate?

Tags: decimal, floating-accuracy, bc

It is possible to print to several hundred decimal places a square root in `bc`, as it is in C. However in C it is only accurate to 15. I have checked the square root of 2 to 50 decimal places and it is accurate but what is the limit in `bc`? I can't find any reference to this.

Comment: bash does not do floating point math. How exactly are you taking square roots?

Comment: Use `bc` for arbitrary precision arithmetic. bash arithmetic is integer only.

Comment: Sorry - of course I meant bc.

Comment: The `bc` tag even says _arbitrary precision_. Have you tried looking up what that means?

Comment: @Useless: Arbitrary precision does not mean complete accuracy.

Comment: GNU bc (at least) uses Newton's method until consecutive approximations are the same to the precision requested. There's no such thing as complete accuracy, but it should be able to calculate correctly as many digits as you ask for, so long as they fit in memory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To how many decimal places is bc accurate?

`bc` is an *arbitrary precision* calculator. Arbitrary precision just tells us how many digits it can *represent* (as many as will fit in memory), but doesn't tell us anything about accuracy.

> However in C it is only accurate to 15

C uses your processor's built-in floating point hardware. This is fast, but has a fixed number of bits to represent each number, so is obviously fixed rather than arbitrary precision.

Any arbitrary precision system will have more ... precision than this, but could of course still be inaccurate. Knowing how many digits can be stored doesn't tell us whether they're correct.

---

However, the GNU implementation of `bc` is open source, so we can just see what it does.

The `bc_sqrt` function uses an iterative approximation (Newton's method, although the same technique was apparently known by the Babylonians in at least 1,000BC).

This approximation is just run, improving each time, until two consecutive guesses differ by less than the precision requested. That is, if you ask for 1,000 digits, it'll keep going until the difference is at most in the 1,001st digit.

The only exception is when you ask for an N-digit result and the original number has more than N digits. It'll use the larger of the two as its target precision.

Since the convergence rate of this algorithm is faster than one digit per iteration, there seems little risk of two consecutive iterations agreeing to some N digits without also being correct to N digits.